# Java library to partially escape HTML code

Tags: java, library, html

I'm implementing an email web client. Sometimes some emails come with HTML content. For security reasons I don't want to render the HTML code as it comes from the original source, but escape or even change the value of some unsafe elements or properties. I was about to start working on a library to do this, but I thought that maybe there is already some work done on this.

Is there any Java library that already does this?

Some examples of functionality I'm looking for:

- Changing property "src" in element "img" for a stakeholder image
- Remove "stript" elements.
- Remove "import" at-rule.

I don't mind if such library is open-source or proprietary, just want to know if there is something already done about it.

Answer (score 6):

After some days I found [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do such thing, they even have a special method to do it: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer.

However, this library loads all the content first (it uses a model similar to XML's DOM) So this is not a perfect solution.

I'm going to leave my answer here but I'm not going to "accept it" straight away in hope someone else comes up with a better solution (something similar to XML's SAX)